# maven surefire report plugin not running the test cases

Tags: maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have configured **surefire report plugin** to my Spring+Maven  based project to generate test report(s) and the surefire report plugin able to identify my test class but not running the test cases present in it.

Dependency used in pom.xml

```
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

While building the project it genertes the result as bellow

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.thales.idct.controller.LopaReConfigControllerTest
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@1829ae5e
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.225 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
```

Even the same things is present in *.html report as well.

Bellow is my test case code

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class LopaReConfigControllerTest {


    public static final MediaType APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 = new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(), Charset.forName("utf8"));

    // Application dependency 

    private MockMvc mvc;
    private LopaReConfigRepositoryImpl lopaImpl;

    /*@Spy
    @InjectMocks
    LopaReConfigService lopaReConfigService = new LopaReConfigService();*/

    @Mock
    LopaReConfigService lopaReConfigService;

    @Mock
    CommonUtil commonUtil;

    @Mock
    ProcessLopaReconfigFile processLopaReconfigFile;

    @Mock
    DBImportRepository dbImportRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    MockHttpSession session;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext context;

    @InjectMocks
    LopaReConfigController lopaReConfigController;

    @Mock
    UserSessionPool sessionPool;

    // Building and Injecting mocked dependency(s) to controller 

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        // Process mock annotations
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(lopaReConfigController).build();

        lopaImpl = new LopaReConfigRepositoryImpl();
    }

    @Test
    public void test_getSeatLayoutDisplay() throws Exception {

        // Construct JSON data to pass as parameter

        BASeatkitDataFeeder seatKitDataFeeder = new BASeatkitDataFeeder();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        CommonUtil util = new CommonUtil();
        StringBuffer filePathBuff = new StringBuffer();
        String jsonStub = "";
        String columnXMl = ""; 

        filePathBuff.append(util.getLopaReConfigPath("RAJESH-300ER", "RAJESH-300ER-B777-v300B"));
        filePathBuff.append(LoadPropertyFiles.getInstance().getProperty("INPUT"));

        //seatKitDataFeeder.setFilepath(XmlFilePath);

        seatKitDataFeeder.setMode("");
        seatKitDataFeeder.setFilename("");
        seatKitDataFeeder.setBuildVersion("Base");
        seatKitDataFeeder.setCarrierName("RAJESH-300ER");
        seatKitDataFeeder.setDbId("1558");
        seatKitDataFeeder.setDbName("RAJESH-300ER-B777-v300B");
        seatKitDataFeeder.setSessionId(session.getId());
        seatKitDataFeeder.setFilepath(filePathBuff.toString());

        String seatKitXmlFilePath = filePathBuff.append(LoadPropertyFiles.getInstance().getProperty("XMLS")).toString();
        columnXMl = filePathBuff.append(Constants.COLUMN_XML_FILENAME).toString();

        BASeatKitInfo BAinfo = lopaImpl.getBASeatKit(seatKitXmlFilePath);
        KitLayout kitLayout = lopaImpl.getBAColumnSeatKit(seatKitXmlFilePath+Constants.SEATKIT_COLUMN_XML_FILENAME,columnXMl);

        // Mock the service results and feed 

        when(commonUtil.getLopaReConfigPath("RAJESH-300ER", "RAJESH-300ER-B777-v300B")).thenReturn(filePathBuff.toString());
        when(lopaReConfigService.getBASeatKit(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(BAinfo);
        when(lopaReConfigService.getBAColumnSeatKit(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(kitLayout);

        // Construct JSON Object

        jsonStub = gson.toJson(seatKitDataFeeder);

        // Test method logic 

        mvc.perform(post("/getSeatLayoutDisplay")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(jsonStub))
            .andExpect(status().isOk()) // After hitting specific URL/URI check the status code fall under 200 series
            .andExpect(content().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)); // Check the return statement is JSON
            //.andExpect(jsonPath("$.fieldErrors", hasSize(1)));
        // Verify that the getBASeatKit() method of the lopaReConfigService is called only once during execution.

        verify(lopaReConfigService, times(0)).getBASeatKit(seatKitXmlFilePath);
        verify(lopaReConfigService, times(0)).getBAColumnSeatKit(seatKitDataFeeder.getFilepath(),columnXMl);
    }


    @Test
    public void testGetBAColumnSeatKit() throws Exception{
        BAColumnSeatkitDataFeeder seatKitDataFeeder = new BAColumnSeatkitDataFeeder();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        CommonUtil util = new CommonUtil();
        StringBuffer filePathBuff = new StringBuffer();
        String jsonStub = "";
        String columnXMl = ""; 
        String centerXmlFilePath = "";

        LopaReConfigController cntrl = PowerMockito.spy(lopaReConfigController);


        seatKitDataFeeder.setMode("");
        seatKitDataFeeder.setFileName("");
        seatKitDataFeeder.setBuildVersion("Base");
        seatKitDataFeeder.setCarrierName("BRITISH");
        seatKitDataFeeder.setDbId("1514");
        seatKitDataFeeder.setDbName("BRITISH-B787-PI-2-8");
        seatKitDataFeeder.setSessionId(session.getId());
        seatKitDataFeeder.setFilePath(filePathBuff.toString());

        when(processLopaReconfigFile.getImportStatus(Integer.parseInt(seatKitDataFeeder.getDbId()))).thenReturn(Constants.SUCCESS);

        filePathBuff = new StringBuffer(util.getLopaReConfigPath(seatKitDataFeeder.getCarrierName(),seatKitDataFeeder.getDbName()));
        filePathBuff.append(LoadPropertyFiles.getInstance().getProperty("INPUT"));
        String seatKitXmlFilePath = filePathBuff.append(LoadPropertyFiles.getInstance().getProperty("XMLS")).toString();

        StringBuffer columnXmlFileBuf = new StringBuffer(filePathBuff);
        columnXmlFileBuf.append(Constants.COLUMN_XML_FILENAME);
        String leftXmlFilePath = filePathBuff.append(Constants.COLUMN_SEATKIT).toString();
        String columnXmlFilePath = columnXmlFileBuf.toString();

        if("Base".equalsIgnoreCase(seatKitDataFeeder.getBuildVersion())){

            centerXmlFilePath = leftXmlFilePath;

        } else {

            centerXmlFilePath=lopaImpl.getLopaFilePath(seatKitDataFeeder.getBuildVersion(),seatKitDataFeeder.getDbId());
        }

        BASeatKitInfo seatKitInfo = lopaImpl.getBASeatKit(seatKitXmlFilePath);
        KitLayout   columnSeatKitLeft = lopaImpl.getBAColumnSeatKit(leftXmlFilePath,columnXmlFilePath);
        KitLayout   columnSeatKitCenter = lopaImpl.getBAColumnSeatKit(centerXmlFilePath,columnXmlFilePath);
        Map<String,String> powerMap = lopaImpl.getPowerUnitInfo(seatKitXmlFilePath);
        List<LayoutDesignVersionEntity> listLDVE = dbImportRepository.getLayoutDesignVersionList(Integer.parseInt(seatKitDataFeeder.getDbId()));


        User user = new User();

        user.setAirlineName("BRITISH-B787-PI-2-8");
        user.setGroupName("FFF");
        user.setLastLoginTime("12:12:12 10:09:09.656");
        user.setPassword("FFF");
        user.setUserName("FFF");


        UserSessionPool.getInstance().addUser(user);

//      when(commonUtil.getLopaReConfigPath(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(filePathBuff.toString());

        //when(commonUtil.getLopaReConfigPath("RAJESH-300ER", "RAJESH-300ER-B777-v300B")).thenReturn(filePathBuff.toString());
        when(commonUtil.getLopaReConfigPath("RAJESH-300ER", "RAJESH-300ER-B777-v300B")).thenReturn(filePathBuff.toString());
        when(lopaReConfigService.getBASeatKit(seatKitXmlFilePath)).thenReturn(seatKitInfo);
        when(lopaReConfigService.getBAColumnSeatKit(leftXmlFilePath,columnXmlFilePath)).thenReturn(columnSeatKitLeft);
        when(lopaReConfigService.getBAColumnSeatKit(centerXmlFilePath,columnXmlFilePath)).thenReturn(columnSeatKitCenter);
        when(lopaReConfigService.getPowerUnitInfo(seatKitXmlFilePath)).thenReturn(powerMap);
        when(dbImportRepository.getLayoutDesignVersionList(Integer.parseInt(seatKitDataFeeder.getDbId()))).thenReturn(listLDVE);

        jsonStub = gson.toJson(seatKitDataFeeder);
        System.out.println(jsonStub);

        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(cntrl,"isValidUser",seatKitDataFeeder.getSessionId());

        mvc.perform(post("/getSeatKitAndLopaInfo")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(jsonStub))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());//.andExpect(jsonPath("airline", "B787-8").exists());// After hitting specific URL/URI check the status code fall under 200 series
                //.andExpect(content().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));// Check the return statement is JSON

        verify(lopaReConfigService, times(0)).getBASeatKit(seatKitXmlFilePath);

    }
}
```

How can I run test cases present in my test class..?
Is there any better test case reporting tool..?

My POM.xml file is as bellow

```
<build>
    <finalName>${pom.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jopendocument/jOpenDocument -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jopendocument</groupId>
        <artifactId>jOpenDocument</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-archiver</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-alpha4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.53</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Unit testing dependency API's -->

    <!--Testing -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- this is included in junit, make sure junit it version 4.11 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${powermock.version}</version> -->
        <version>1.5.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: are your test classes located under /src/test/java ?

Comment: Yes my test class is present inside  /src/test/java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please delete the **maven-surefire-report-plugin** from reporting tag place the bellow plugin inside the build tag

```
     <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                        <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>junit</name>
                        <value>true</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>
```